# Line of code runs fine in command window but not in editor

Tags: matrix, octave

I have a matrix, 18 rows 3 columns. The three columns represent the positions of objects as x,y z coordinates. I readjust my objects based on their distance from another matrix (`matrix2`) like so:

```
ShiftLeft = max(matrix(:,1)) - min(matrix2(:,1))
```

the shift depends on how far away the rightmost coordinate of `matrix` is from the leftmost coordinate of `matrix2`.

I have checked the value of `ShiftLeft` in the command window multiple times and it's working fine, its value equals 7.

All I want is to create a new matrix which is the first matrix, but shifted.

I type

```
matrix + [shiftleft 0 0]
```

into the command window and it produces a new matrix, which is what I want.

I also have tried

```
newmatrix = matrix + [shiftleft 0 0]
```

in the command window and again, it produces the matrix I want. 
But when I run my script it tells me it is this line which is producing an error:

> ```
> syntax error 
> newmatrix = matrix + [shiftleft 0 0]
>        ^
> ```

What could be producing this error?

I originally thought that it was the naming of the matrix that was causing the error but naming it in the command window is working fine.

Comment: Octave and MATLAB are case sensitive, so make sure you are using `ShiftLeft` and not `shiftleft` in your above calculations. There's no other reason I can think of that displaying the output wouldn't give you an error but assigning it to a variable would.

Answer (score 1):

As [gnovice pointed out in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53159100/line-of-code-runs-fine-in-command-window-but-not-in-editor#comment93209148_53159100), `ShiftLeft` is not the same as `shiftleft`. It is likely that you have another variable `shiftleft` defined in your workspace, and therefore the statement `matrix + [shiftleft 0 0]` works fine in your command window. But this variable would not be defined in the script, and therefore you get an error message.

For example, I see this in the Octave command window:

```
>> ShiftLeft=0
ShiftLeft = 0
>> shiftleft
error: 'shiftleft' undefined near line 1 column 1
```